# C# XML Deserialize ignore Default value attribute

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I am having a class with a set of properties that I use as user level settings. Each property has a Default Value attribute. Few has XmlIgnore attribute to avoid the serialization.

When serializing this class object as memory stream and it writes it correct, but while de-serializing it actually creates an object with all the properties default value which was not part of the serialized object. How can I ignore this default value initialization for few properties? Thanks in advance.

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new mlSerializer(typeof(DisplayPreferences));
DisplayPreferences newPrefs = null;
MemoryStream ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(prefs));
newPrefs = (DisplayPreferences)serializer.Deserialize(ms);
if (newPrefs != null)
{
   newPrefs.CopyTo(Editor.prefs);
}
```

This app is built in .NET 4.6 (winforms)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've given very little information on *how* you are de-serializing them (a code snippet would help), but I assume you are de-serializing them into a typed object. If that is the case, then what you are experiencing is standard behavior. That is the whole point of the default value, you can't "partially de-serialize a typed object".

What you can do however is either:

- de-serializing the object into a raw xmlObject, and write a custom serializer for it.
- Make the properties nullable, this is typically where DTO's are useful.See below.

  ```
   public class SomeTypedObjectDTO
   {
         public Guid? NullableGuid { get; set; }
         public int? NullableInt { get; set; }
   }
  ```

----UPDATE----

I tired to keep this in line with your code. Lets say you have the following object.

```
public class DisplayPreferences
{
   public Guid Id { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public int Level { get; set; }
   public bool CanDisplay { get; set; }
}
```

And lets say you only want to serialize the "CanDisplay" and the "level" properties. You can create a DTO (Data Transfer object) for it, which is basically a stripped down version of the original object.

**DTO:**

```
public class DisplayPreferencesDTO
{
    public int Level { get; set; }
    public bool CanDisplay { get; set; }
}
```

Then I believe all you need to do is change the generic typeof() to use the DTO instead of the actual object.

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new mlSerializer(typeof(DisplayPreferencesDTO));
```

You can then map the DTO back to the original object when you like and *if* you like. You can either do this mapping manually or use a framework called [Automapper](https://automapper.org/). Automapper was explicitly designed for mapping DTO's.

Comment: Thanks Geoffrey for quick response.
Yes, you are right. I am de-serializing into a typed object. updated my question with code sample. I cannot make it as nullable as I do many comparisons and displaying these properties in to property grid contriol.

Comment: All good, a typical workaround for these issues is to create a DTO with only the properties you need. You can then use something like automapper to map your DTO's. If you need me to clarify let me know.

Comment: Geoffrey, This is winforms application built in .NET 4.6.2
I am not familiar with  creating DTO. My actual implementation is to get the user level preferences and serialize it, convert that to a string and keep in the system clipboard as part of my binary file. Then while pasting, I will get the string back and then convert to a memory stream to de-serialize it. Finally I will replace the new de-serialized result to my actual object.

Comment: Okay, I'll update my answer to see if it helps clarify what I mean.

Answer (score -1):

You may want to make them as null? just make them to nullable prop
such as make a *int* to *int?*

Comment: No I cannot make it as null as I do comparisons and also display it in property grid.